# Instagram Profile Layout With Css ( styled-components )

Tags: css, styled-components

I'm trying to do the Instagram user's photos layout in react, and actually i've done it before in a css grid course

**The PROBLEM** is that, this time is not working, and i don't know how, i've tried so many things and i don't know why my img doesn't resize to the size i want

*Let me show you the code*

So, this is the way i did it

```
  return (
    <UserPhotosHero>
      <ContainUserPhotos>
        {specificPhotos &&
          specificPhotos.map(photo => {
            return (
              <AnimatePresence>
                <UserPersonalPhotos
                  key={photo.id}
                  variants={PopUp}
                  initial="hidden"
                  animate="visible"
                >
                  <img src={photo.photo} />
                </UserPersonalPhotos>
              </AnimatePresence>
            );
          })}
      </ContainUserPhotos>
    </UserPhotosHero>
  );
};
```

And these are the styles

```
// User Photos

export const UserPhotosHero = styles.section`

width: 75%;
min-height: 40vh;

margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 6rem;
margin-top: 4.5rem;


`;

export const ContainUserPhotos = styles.div`

display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(100px, 293px));
justify-content: center;
grid-gap: 2.8rem;

`;

export const UserPersonalPhotos = styles(motion.div)`

position: relative;
cursor: pointer;

z-index: 2;

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}

`;
```

**Expected Output**: So as i've mentioned before, i did it in another course,and i have to looked to the code so i can guide myselfd, and, what i was expecting to happen is, 3 columns, each column is a div, and evey div's size would be width 293px, height 293px, and if i make the window close, it would resize both width and height, but, this is what i get

An image with the width i was expecting but, the height isn't close to 293px

[Instagram's (ugly) layout photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ESXU.png)

Why the size of the img is not getting even close to 293px ? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are at the mercy of your image's aspect ratio given the code you've provided. If your image isn't a square, you're not gonna get a square. Nothing in your styled components CSS will set the height; `grid-template-columns` will only specify the width. If you want a square image, something you might want to try is wrapping your image in a div with `padding-bottom: 100%` and `position: relative`, then if you absolutely positioned your image it should give you what you want...something like this (please be advised I haven't tested this code):

```
.image-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 100%; // this will give you an aspect ratio of 1:1 (square)
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
  }
}
```

Also...make sure you add a key to the `<AnimatePresence />` component within your map function...arrays of components in React all require a unique key. You could probably just use the image's source as your key.

Comment: Mate, that's what i'm talking about, know i can keep up with my project, thanks legend